# How to Power on Remote System Remotely?

Tags: linux, hardware, remote-desktop, automation

Lot's of time I have received call form Developers/QA to Power on their office machine. And I am trying to do R&D on this, Searched over the internet and trying to use the suggested tool in LAN Network, but still not success.

**Wake-on-LAN** Option enabled in **BIOS**

**Wake on magic packet** enabled from **Windows Device Manager =>Network Device => Properties => Advanced tab**.

Is there any **DOS or Bash Script** can i use to turn on the remote office machine (Linux/MAC/Windows) over the LAN (WAN-Static IP).

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking for "Wake on LAN", which is supported by DELL Optiplex systems (at least in principle).

- Enable "Wake on LAN" in the BIOS of the target.
- Disable "Deep Sleep" in the BIOS of the target.
- On your "other" Computer (assuming it is in the same LAN) install [wakeonlan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aquilawol/). This tool can send "magic packets" to the target.
- Now create a file (lets call it optiplex.wol) in your home directory with just MAC address of the Optiplex (like `54:04:a6:a0:90:a1`) as content.
- Type `wakeonlan -f optiplex.wol` - the machine should start within seconds

Comment: Yes Correct ! let me try on this.

Comment: On a side note: if your developers ask this on a daily basis and around the same time, you might benefit from doing more than just WoL and configuring the BIOS itself to start the computer at a certain time. I used to have this configured in my Asus P8P67. Not sure if Optiplex supports it though. And if the support isn't there, or not accurate enough, you can always set the script to autostart. Also, I can't find any mention in the question of Optiplex, so why do you assume that they're using one?

Answer (score 2):

On your Linux machine, simply issue `wol <MAC>`
For other options, give a look at [wol manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wol)

Comment: On Ubuntu: _wol_  command Not Found

I Just hit     _wakeonlan_   

The program 'wakeonlan' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:

    apt-get install wakeonlan

Comment: Ramesh Chand you got that error because you don't have `wol` installed. Just type the following and if it is in your repository it will install: `sudo apt-get install -y wol`